# Maximum disk where a complex function can be developed as a power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked which is the maximum disk centered at $0$ where I can develop $f(z)=\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z-1})$ as a power series.

My answer: Since $$f'(z)=\frac{\sin(1/(z-1))}{(z-1)^2}$$ $f(z)$ is not holomorphic in $z=1$ and therefore the maximum disk is the disk centered at $0$ with radius $1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\cos(z)$ is entire and $ 1/(z-1)$ is analytic at $z=0$ so $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n$ for $|z| < r$. Once you have shown that $z=1$ is a singularity of $f$ you know that $r \le 1$. But what is your **proof** that $r=1$ ?

Comment: @reuns That is what I don't understand. Why can I take $r=1$ if we have a singularity at $z=1$? Isn't this point, that belongs to the disk of radius $1$ precisely what we have to avoid?

Comment: $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n$ converges for $|z| < r$, on $|z| = r$ the series may diverge and $f$ may have have a singularity (try with the geometric series and its pole at $z=1$)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the open disc of radius $1$, centered at $0$.

Comment: Why? The function is not holomorphic at $z=1$ which belongs to the boundary of the disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$.

Comment: You're right,  but every point in $\{z: \vert z\vert\lt1\}$ is different than $1$.  So the derivative exists,  that is, it's holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Taylor representation theorem asserts that Taylor series centered at a point $a$ of an anaytic function $f$ always converges to $f(z)$ on any open disk centered at $a$ contained in the domain of $f$. In your case, this assures that the Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ centered at $0$ of $\cos\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$ converges in the disk $D_1(0)$.

But it cannot converge on any larger disk $D_r(0)$ ($r>1$). Because oterwise we would have$$\lim_{z\to1}\cos\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)=\lim_{z\to1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n,$$but the limit $\lim_{z\to1}\cos\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Otherwise since $\cos(s)$ is entire it is elementary (composition of the two Taylor series at $z=0$ and $s=-1$) to show the Taylor series converges for $|z| < 1$